# Conditions in R-Studio

Tags: r, if-statement, sampling

I have this problem statement, I am having this as an example:

```
Product_id  product_type    views   inventory
1   producttype1    Y   Y
2   producttype2    N   N
3   producttype3    Y   Y
4   producttype4    N   N
5   producttype5    Y   Y
6   producttype6    N   N
7   producttype7    Y   Y
8   producttype1    N   N
9   producttype2    Y   Y
10  producttype3    N   N
11  producttype4    Y   Y
12  producttype5    N   N
13  producttype6    Y   Y
14  producttype7    N   N
15  producttype7    Y   Y
```

I have 10 millions as population from where I am trying to extract a 10% sample of population and I have to group them by product_type, views. But in the end when I get the sample, if the sample it is less than 500k then I can keep it as it is but in the scenario when the sample is highest than 500k I have to reduce the sample at 500k. This is the code that I wrote to group and to extract the 10% sample:

```
MPSSAMPLE %>% 
  group_by(product_type, views) %>%
  sample_frac(.10) -> sampledData
```

Can anyone help me with the conditions?

Comment: Why does it say "R-Studio" in the title when the question has nothing to do in whatever context R is being used?

Comment: I am using R for this problem statement. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min` to get minimum between 500k or 10% of the sample population of the group.

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 500000

MPSSAMPLE %>% 
  group_by(product_type, views) %>%
  sample_n(min(n() * 0.1, n)) -> sampledData
```